# Django user model in submodel

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.x, django-authentication

In my current project I'm replacing the default django user model. As the number of models started growing I decided to split the implementation into several folders, but now django can't find my user model.

I had this, which works:

```
djutils
    models.py
        UserManager
        User
```

I changed to this and it doesn't work anymore

```
djutils
    models
        __init__.py
            from djutils.models.user import UserManager, User
        user.py
            UserManager
            User
```

Shouldn't it still import the models? I get:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
auth.user: Model has been swapped out for 'djutils.User' which has not been installed or is abstract.
```

I have this in my settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'djutils.User'
```

(Notice the first case works)

Please advise!
Regards

**Edit**

```
djutils
    models
        __init__.py
            from __future__ import absolute_import

            from djutils.models.base import Manager, PrivateModel, Model
            from djutils.models.user import UserManager, User
            from djutils.models.passwordrecovery import PasswordRecoveryManager, PasswordRecovery

        user.py
            from djutils.models.base import Manager, Model
            from djutils import mail
            from djutils import settings
            from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
            from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
            from django.utils import timezone
            from djutils import fields

            class UserManager(Manager, BaseUserManager):
                def create_user_instance(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields):
                    return user

                def create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields):
                    return user

                def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, **extra_fields):
                    return user

            class User(Model(20), AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
                # Basico info
                first_name = fields.NameField(max_length=20, help_text=_('First name'))
                last_name = fields.NameField(max_length=20, help_text=_('Last name'))
                email = fields.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text=_('Email'))

                url = fields.URLField(help_text=_('Personal homepage'))
                bio = fields.TextField(help_text=_('Biographic details'))
                #picture = fields.ImageField(help_text=_('Profile picture'))

                # Permissions
                is_active = fields.BooleanField(default=False, help_text=_('Active user'))
                is_staff = fields.BooleanField(default=False, help_text=_('Staff member'))

                # Logging
                date_joined = fields.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

                # A string describing the name of the field on the User model that is used as the unique identifier
                USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

                # A list of the field names that must be provided when creating a user via the createsuperuser management command
                REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'password']

                # Fields that are not returned by get_public
                PRIVATE = ['is_active', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'last_login', 'groups', 'user_permissions', 'password', 'id']

                # Model manager
                objects = UserManager()

                class Meta:
                    swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
                    permissions = ()

                def send_mail(self, request, subject, body, context={}):
                    mail.send_mail(request, subject, body, [self.email], context)

                def send_confirmation_email(self, request, context={}):
                    self.send_mail(request, settings.CONFIRMATION_SUBJECT, settings.CONFIRMATION_TEMPLATE, dict(context, **{
                        'redirect': request.build_absolute_uri(settings.CONFIRMATION_REDIRECT_URL)
                    }))
```

Comment: try to change
`from djutils.models.user import UserManager, User`
to
`from .user import UserManager, User`
what happens?

Comment: Does it work if you use `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'djutils.models.User'`?

Comment: @JosvicZammit the same. The imports seem to be working fine.

Comment: @Aya that is not valid in django. AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'myapp.MyUser'. If I do that I get "auth.user: AUTH_USER_MODEL is not of the form 'app_label.app_name'"

Comment: When you moved `models.py`, did you perhaps leave a `models.pyc` behind which is being picked up?

Comment: @Aya I cleaned all my .pyc files, same thing. However, one curious thing: after running manager.py syncdb both __init__.py and user.py in the models folder generated a .pyc file again ! This tells me that the modules are being imported

Comment: Well, I tried doing something similar, and couldn't reproduce the fault, so you may have to post some of the source code for `__init__.py` and `user.py`.

Comment: Could you please show me what you have tried? What's your django version?

Comment: should it still not be `djutil.user.User` in `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: @karthikr where are you suggesting I write that?

Comment: @Aya see Alasdair's answer. It's strange that you couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AndréFratelli Strange. `./manage.py runserver` started just fine with an `AUTH_USER_MODEL` pointing to a class without the `app_label` but a `./manage.py sql myapp` doesn't show the table for the custom user. Ironically, I'd already had to do the `app_label` hack for another project, so I should've known that - I'd just forgotten all about it. :)

Comment: Ah! runserver does not try to validate the models, that's why it worked ;) if you tried syncdb it would probably have failed

Comment: @AndréFratelli In that case, it's a bit naughty for it to print `Validating models... 0 errors found` immediately after running `./manage.py runserver`. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `app_label = 'djutils'` in your User model's `Meta` class.

See the [`app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) docs for more info.